# Numpy - Compare elements in two 2D arrays and replace values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, replace, conditional-statements

I have a specific requirement for this problem. I need it to be simple and fast.

**My problem:**
I have two 2D arrays and I need to replace values in 1. array by values in 2. array according to condition. That is if element in x,y position in 1. array is smaller than element in x,y position in 2. array, then replace element in 1. array by element in 2. array.

what I tried and is not working:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.randint(3,size=(2, 2))
arr2 = np.random.randint(3,size=(2, 2))
print(arr)
print(arr2)

arr[arr<arr2]=arr2 # Doesnt work.
```

This raises TypeError:

*TypeError: NumPy boolean array indexing assignment requires a 0 or 1-dimensional input, input has 2 dimensions*.

I can see, that it would be possible to iterate through columns or rows, but I believe it can be done without iteration.

Thanks in advance

Comment: arr[arr<arr2]=arr2[arr<arr2]

Comment: The following should also work
np.where(arr>=arr2, arr, arr2)

Comment: Thanks for answers. Somebody posted this solution that worked for me too np.copyto(temp, dist, where=temp<dist). Since its deleted, I will keep it here